# QGIS Buffer Covering Whole Screen

Tags: qgis

When I try to draw a 2.5 mile buffer around a point in QGIS, the entire screen is filled with the buffer.  I have changed the projection of the shapefile and the project, as you can see from the screenshots.  This is using QGIS 3.8.0
[image: Properties screenshot]
[image: CRS settings]

Comment: how did you change the projection of the shapefile exactly?

Comment: You didn't actually change your data, just the metadata so you are now lying to QGIS and it is confused.

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate issue is not helpful Ian.  I searched all around for a solution, and saw people being giving the same answer about changing the projection repeatedly.  This obviously is not that simple in my case.

To set the projection, I chose one when importing the data via CSV.  Once the data was imported, I saved the feature as a new shapefile, again selecting that projection.  I also set the default projection of any new files to that projection.

Comment: to get you on the right track: the issue you are facing is due to you *assigning* a (wrong) CRS instead of *reprojecting* into the correct CRS; the data itself is likely referenced in a geographic coordinate system, and on import you will have to select that CRS (I assume EPSG:4326, you will need to check with the data provider). then you need to *reproject* that layer (in this case save as shapefile with the desired projection, QGIS will then automatically *reproject* into the target CRS).

Answer (score 0):

When you're drawing the buffer are you definitely using the correct measurement (See below)? The screen might be filled at first but have you tried to right-click on the layer and then zoom to Extent'. This will zoom with your buffer centred.

[image]